# AsyncTask giving error, trying to pass map<Date,String>

Tags: android

[image]I am trying to pass a map to an AsyncTask below is my code:

```
private class MagicCall extends AsyncTask<Map<Date,String>, Integer, String> {

        ProgressDialog Asycdialog = new ProgressDialog(LoaderClass.this);
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            Asycdialog.setMessage("Working");
            Asycdialog.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            //hide the dialog
            Asycdialog.setMessage(result);
            Asycdialog.dismiss();
            t3.setText(result); 
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }



        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Map<Date, String> ... mP) {

        //  String B = insertNameBD(params);

            Map<Date, String> Sx = new TreeMap<Date, String>(); 
            String value = null;
            Sx = mP; 


            return ""; 

        }



        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {

            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            Asycdialog.setMessage(""+values);
        }

    }
```

However when I try to reference Sx to mP it gives me an error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map[] to Map

I am unable to know what is wrong with the assignment, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns in the form of array so your data is available in 0 th position..Change this line in doInBackground

```
Sx = mP;
```

into

```
Sx = mP[0];
```

Comment: What does that mean? Will the values held in my map change due to this assignment?

Comment: three dots means it is in the form of array your data is is available in 0th position..

Answer (score 2):

That's because `mP` is an array. `...` accepts multiple parameters and puts them in an array. Use `mp[0]` instead (before, make sure the array contains any data).

For example, this method:

```
public void foo(int...bar){}
```

can be called like

```
foo(2,6,3,82);
```

then bar is an array, that contains `{2,6,3,82}` in that method

Answer (score 1):

It is correct. Because the three dots notation, `vargars`, "translate" the argument in an array.  The three points means that you can pass from 0 the n values of the same type to the method. And then you can access it like an Array, index basis, from `0` to `n-1`. It should also accept an array as parameter

Comment: Thanks for clearing it to me, wish if I could accept two answers!

Comment: Just wonderting what if I dont want it in the array form, can I get rid of those dots?

Comment: the dots are already an array, why do you want to rid of them?